# Apple TV move down viewController when tab bar shown

Tags: ios, objective-c, tvos, apple-tv

I woluld like to move down my view controller content (that is, the whole view) when the tab bar is shown. Is there any way to do it automatically? Or it has to be done programmatically?

Comment: What i think when you come to the view controller from the tabBar and if you have chosen to "extend edges" from XIB checked the options "under top bar"."under bottom bar" your view controller switch to full screen. Please provide a detail explanation of the problem with screenshots if possible that would really help people to solve the issue. Thanks

Comment: You were right, it was as simple as unchecking "under top bar" and "under bottom bar"

Comment: Cool. Glad your issue is now resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was simple. Just unchecking "under top bar" and "under bottom bar" in Interface Builder make the view "move down" when the tab bar is shown